# how to merge an array of objects by comparing one object in it

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following is my array of objects

```
[
        {
            "date": "2022-08-26",
            "names": "TOTAL_REVENUE",
            "values": "253599593.31",
            "tabs": "Revenue"
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-08-26",
            "names": "TOTAL_VOICE_REVENUE",
            "values": "142706038.15",
            "tabs": "Revenue"
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-08-27",
            "names": "TOTAL_DATA_REVENUE",
            "values": "97825740.6",
            "tabs": "Revenue"
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-08-27",
            "names": "TOTAL_REVENUE_SM",
            "values": "6731513.29",
            "tabs": "Revenue"
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-08-27",
            "names": "TOTAL_BUNDLE_REVENUE",
            "values": "0",
            "tabs": "Revenue"
        }]
```

I want to club all the objects according to the date like the following

```
[
        {
            "date": "2022-08-26",
            "TOTAL_REVENUE": "253599593.31",
            "TOTAL_VOICE_REVENUE":"142706038.15"
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-08-27",
            "TOTAL_DATA_REVENUE": "97825740.6",
            "TOTAL_REVENUE_SM": "6731513.29",
            "TOTAL_BUNDLE_REVENUE": "0"
        }]
```

is there any way to format like this

Comment: Anything you have tried till now?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. [Documentation on loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a normal loop and an object to create the result. Like this:

```js
  const input = [
    {
      date: "2022-08-26",
      names: "TOTAL_REVENUE",
      values: "253599593.31",
      tabs: "Revenue"
    },
    {
      date: "2022-08-26",
      names: "TOTAL_VOICE_REVENUE",
      values: "142706038.15",
      tabs: "Revenue"
    },
    {
      date: "2022-08-27",
      names: "TOTAL_DATA_REVENUE",
      values: "97825740.6",
      tabs: "Revenue"
    },
    {
      date: "2022-08-27",
      names: "TOTAL_REVENUE_SM",
      values: "6731513.29",
      tabs: "Revenue"
    },
    {
      date: "2022-08-27",
      names: "TOTAL_BUNDLE_REVENUE",
      values: "0",
      tabs: "Revenue"
    }
  ];

  function group(arr) {
    const dateGroups = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      const { date, names, values } = arr[i];
      dateGroups[date] ??= {};
      dateGroups[date].date = date;
      dateGroups[date][names] ??= 0;
      dateGroups[date][names] += +values;
    }
    return Object.values(dateGroups);
  }

  console.log(group(input));
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: can u please convert this to simple javascript code for easy understatnding

Comment: What means simple javascript?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming all the elements in `input` have a unique `date`/`names` combination**, you could use the following:

```js
function answer(input) {
  const revenue = new Map();
  
  for (const { date, names, values } of input) {
    if (!revenue.has(date)) revenue.set(date, { date });
    revenue.get(date)[names] = values;
  }
  
  return Array.from(revenue.values());
}

const input = [{
  date: "2022-08-26",
  names: "TOTAL_REVENUE",
  values: "253599593.31",
  tabs: "Revenue"
}, {
  date: "2022-08-26",
  names: "TOTAL_VOICE_REVENUE",
  values: "142706038.15",
  tabs: "Revenue"
}, {
  date: "2022-08-27",
  names: "TOTAL_DATA_REVENUE",
  values: "97825740.6",
  tabs: "Revenue"
}, {
  date: "2022-08-27",
  names: "TOTAL_REVENUE_SM",
  values: "6731513.29",
  tabs: "Revenue"
}, {
  date: "2022-08-27",
  names: "TOTAL_BUNDLE_REVENUE",
  values: "0",
  tabs: "Revenue"
}];

console.log(answer(input));
```

The code above stores the resulting values a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance, so we can easily check its presence and retrieve the value.

In the end the `revenue` structure looks like this:

```
revenue = Map{ // using object-notation to represent the Map contents
  "2022-08-26": {
    "date": "2022-08-26",
    "TOTAL_REVENUE": "253599593.31",
    "TOTAL_VOICE_REVENUE": "142706038.15"
  },
  "2022-08-27": {
    "date": "2022-08-27",
    "TOTAL_DATA_REVENUE": "97825740.6",
    "TOTAL_REVENUE_SM": "6731513.29",
    "TOTAL_BUNDLE_REVENUE": "0"
  }
}
```

Since you want an array containing the results and not a `Map` instance, I'll use `Array.from(lookup.values())` to convert the structure into the desired result.

Note that `revenue.get(date)[names] = values` will **replace** the previous value with the same `date`/`names` combination. That's why this answer only works if all the `date`/`names` combinations are unique.